# Payment using datatrans-inline.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-forms

Im trying to generate a token using datatrans-inline.js
Im having difficulties implementing it in my typescript in Angular2.....

Can anyone help?

Documentation:
https://docs.pci-proxy.com/inline-payment-frames.html

whenever i implement the code

```
Inline.initTokenize( "1234567890", {
   cardNumber: "1234567890123456", 
   cvv: "567"                
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose to fix your issue your need change `cardNumber` and `cvv` according documentation

> Initialize the Inline Mode with your merchantId and specify which DOM element containers should be used to inject the iframes

actually `cardNumber` and `cvv` it is `id` of dom elements

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="card-number-placeholder">Card Number</label>
      <!-- card number container -->
      <div id="card-number-placeholder" style="width: 250px; height: 38px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="cvv-placeholder">Cvv</label>
      <!-- cvv container -->
      <div id="cvv-placeholder" style="width: 90px; height: 38px;"></div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="go">Get Token!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```